# WiFi Agent занимает 80 порт

Tags: macos

Сегодня включил Mac и заметил что apache лежит. При попытке перезапуска

```
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
```

Решил же посмотреть кто же это занял порт

```
lsof -i -P -n
```

Оказалось

```
COMMAND   PID  USER      FD  TYPE DEVICE              SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
WiFiAgent 1658 ninazu    7u  IPv4 0xc747b7ad3566a6fb  0t0      UDP  *:*
```

Почему WiFiAgent занимает порт? 
Предложения. Где это пофиксить, чтоб в дальнейшем не возникало. OSX Sierra

Comment: в логи апача посмотри сначала

Comment: О чем логи говорят???